# Flutter default counter app using BLoC pattern

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to use BLoC for state management.
So I'm trying to rewrite flutter's default counter app using BLoC.
Unfortunately my UI is not redrawn when the **add button** is pressed.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong
I'm using

```
  bloc: ^6.1.0
  equatable: ^1.2.5
  flutter_bloc: ^6.0.6
```

Here is my code

**counter_event.dart**

```
part of 'counter_bloc.dart';

abstract class CounterEvent extends Equatable {
  const CounterEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class IncrementEvent extends CounterEvent {}

class DecrementEvent extends CounterEvent {}
```

**counter_state.dart**

```
part of 'counter_bloc.dart';

class CounterState extends Equatable {
  final int counter;
  const CounterState({@required this.counter});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [counter];
}
```

**counter_bloc.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

part 'counter_event.dart';
part 'counter_state.dart';

class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, CounterState> {
  CounterBloc() : super(CounterState(counter: 0));

  @override
  Stream<CounterState> mapEventToState(CounterEvent event) async* {
    if (state is IncrementEvent) {
      yield CounterState(counter: state.counter + 1);
    } else if (state is DecrementEvent) {
      yield CounterState(counter: state.counter - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the main function

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:counter_bloc/bloc/counter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Home(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  CounterBloc counterBloc = CounterBloc();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, CounterState>(
        cubit: counterBloc,
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                Text(
                  state.counter.toString(),
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          counterBloc.add(IncrementEvent());
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    counterBloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below
Step 1:  `if (event is IncrementEvent)` not `state`
Step 2:  You need `BlocProvider`

```
home: BlocProvider<CounterBloc>(
        create: (context) => CounterBloc(),
        child: Home(
          title: "test",
        ),
      ),
```

Step 3: You need to call `BlocProvider.of<CounterBloc>`

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final CounterBloc counterBloc = BlocProvider.of<CounterBloc>(context);
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

abstract class CounterEvent extends Equatable {
  const CounterEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class IncrementEvent extends CounterEvent {}

class DecrementEvent extends CounterEvent {}

class CounterState extends Equatable {
  final int counter;
  const CounterState({@required this.counter});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [counter];
}

class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, CounterState> {
  CounterBloc() : super(CounterState(counter: 0));

  @override
  Stream<CounterState> mapEventToState(CounterEvent event) async* {
    print(event.toString());
    if (event is IncrementEvent) {
      print("inc");
      yield CounterState(counter: state.counter + 1);
    } else if (state is DecrementEvent) {
      yield CounterState(counter: state.counter - 1);
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: BlocProvider<CounterBloc>(
        create: (context) => CounterBloc(),
        child: Home(
          title: "test",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final CounterBloc counterBloc = BlocProvider.of<CounterBloc>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, CounterState>(
        //cubit: counterBloc,
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                Text(
                  state.counter.toString(),
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print("click");
          counterBloc.add(IncrementEvent());
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

this your wrong

```
if (state is IncrementEvent) {
  yield CounterState(counter: state.counter + 1);
} else if (state is DecrementEvent) {
  yield CounterState(counter: state.counter - 1);
}
```

change to

```
if (event is IncrementEvent) {
  yield CounterState(counter: state.counter + 1);
} else if (event is DecrementEvent) {
  yield CounterState(counter: state.counter - 1);
}
```